# Como detectar se o browser está baixando algum arquivo em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma aplicação onde preciso detectar se o navegador está baixando algum arquivo, seja script, imagem, áudio ou fonte. Como posso fazer isso em JavaScript?

Gostaria de algo desse tipo:

```js
const download = browser_is_downloading();

if (download) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: Acredito que só possa ser feito usando uma extensão https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download .Mas adianto que nunca fiz nada parecido então pode haver outra solução que desconheça.

Comment: Isso em que? Javascript rodando no navegador ou rodando no puppeteer?

Comment: No navegador...

Comment: É impossível, primeiro que iria violar a privacidade do usuário, segundo que esse controle todo é resolvido via HTTP, o gerenciador de downloads pode até vir embutido no navegador, mas não faz parte da comunicação com as páginas web renderizadas diretamente, apesar de utilizar a mesma sessão o download é deslocado para que outro processo o resolva, a 5 anos eu desenvolvi 2 navegadores web para uso especifico, QtWebkit (é o webkit do safari mas dentro do Qt) e outro com Chromium (na verdade é o QtWebEngine), não existe gerenciador de download, vc só tinhas as interfaces ...

Comment: ...  CSS, JS, Cookies, network, etc pra controlar, então o download é claro nunca ocorria, mas claro que tinha a API para receber o tal download, eu escrevi em C++ e Qt meu proprio gerenciador, que recebia a resposta da API quando o usuário solicitava o download e redirecionava a requisição HTTP e sessão para ele, então funcionava igualmente o que ocorre em um navegador, embuti o gerenciador e estava resolvido. Quando migrei de QtWebkit para QtWebEgnine bastou ajustar a API, o gerenciador era o mesmo, mas claro que o sistema de rede do QtWebEngine é diferente do QtWebkit ...

Comment: ... então na visão do usuário o processo foi igual, mas por baixo não era. Isso tudo só contei pra lhe explicar, o que ocorre nos gerenciadores de download é realmente algo a parte, as vezes "alguém" pode até fornecer uma API no navegador que gerencie isso de forma que você controle no navegador, mas na maioria das vezes é de terceiros, como criar uma extensão para navegador que intercepta downloads e envia via postMessage para todas páginas web em um evento que algo foi iniciado.

Comment: Entendi, mas por que um site verificar se há downloads sendo feitos na sessão violaria a privacidade do usuário se os tais arquivos viriam do próprio site ? Por exemplo, se eu crio um site que possui áudios e quero saber se o navegador está baixando esses áudios, porque seria violar a privacidade sendo que os áudios estão vindo do meu servidor ?